# Validating lines in a file using certain specifications

Tags: beginner, c, validation, file, formatting

I have written a program which basically reads a file named "data.txt" line-by-line.  As a line is read, it validates the line with a certain specification.  If the specification is met, it will output the data within a file named data.txt.  If the line does not meet the validation criteria, then it will output that specific line to a separate file named error.txt.

I have finished the code and was wondering if anyone could look at it and see if they could help me with a few points in making the code look more compact and tidy.  I feel I have done the same code over and over again for no reason. I have added comments so the code should make sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used

struct packet{
    int source;        // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int destination;   // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int type;          // 0 - 10 range (int)               // Varibles for the structure
    int port;          // 1 = 1024 (int)
    char data[50];     // 1 - 50 range (char)

};

int main()
{

    char filename[32] = { '\0' } ;   // variables which declare the I/O stream and the filename structure
    char DataLine[71];               // Reads the file one line at a time
    char ErrorLine[71];              // This is the varible that deals with the validation error
    char TempStorage[5];                // Stores data to be validated
    char TempData[50];                   // Stores the data which will be validated
    int  TempS, TempD, TempT, TempP;  // Stores the integer derived from the input file
    int  Flag = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicates a Line has not passed validation
    int  Count = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicated a line has passed validation
    int  Ecount = 0;                  // This counts the number of errors

 struct packet *DataRecords;
 DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));    // This deals with storing the data needed for the next task.

printf("Enter the filename you wish to open\n");
scanf("%s", &filename);
                                      // user inputs the filename
FILE *DataFile;
if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nfile could not be opened. : %s\n", filename);  // If a value of NULL is returned then the program will close.

}
else
{


FILE *ErrorFile = fopen("error.txt","w");                         // This will start searching through the lines and store the lines not passing the validation test to a txt file named "error.txt". 
printf("File has been found, checking validation");

while( fgets (DataLine, 71, DataFile)!=NULL) {
strcpy(ErrorLine, DataLine);
strcpy(TempStorage, strtok(DataLine,":"));
TempS = atoi(TempStorage);
strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));            // these lines of code looks through each line and stores the line within the "Temp Storage" varible, the : token is what the element within the line is seperated by.
TempD = atoi(TempStorage);
strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));
TempT = atoi(TempStorage);
strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));
TempP = atoi(TempStorage);
strcpy(TempData, strtok( NULL, ":"));

    if (TempS < 1 || TempS > 1024) Flag = 1;
    if (TempD < 1 || TempD > 1024) Flag = 1;
    if (TempT < 0 || TempT > 10) Flag = 1;                   // // Validation aspect, if the validation is not met then a flag is added to which then the line is posted within the error file. 
    if (TempP < 1 || TempP > 1024) Flag = 1;
    if (strlen(TempData) < 1 || strlen(TempData)> 50) Flag = 1;
    if (Flag == 1)
    {
        Ecount++;
        printf("Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s",Ecount,TempS,TempD,TempT,TempP,TempData);  
        fprintf(ErrorFile,"%s", ErrorLine);
        // fprintf writes formatted text to the output stream you specify
    }
    else
    {
        DataRecords[Count].source = TempS;
        DataRecords[Count].destination = TempD;
        DataRecords[Count].type = TempT;
        DataRecords[Count].port = TempP;
        strncpy(DataRecords[Count].data,TempData,51);
        Count++; //increment sequence number
        DataRecords = realloc(DataRecords,(Count+1)*sizeof(struct packet));//allocate more memory for packetdata
    } 
Flag = 0;  
}
FILE *DFile = fopen("data2.txt","w");
int ii;
for (ii = 0; ii < Count; ii++)
{
fprintf(DFile,  "%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s",DataRecords[ii].source,    // Where the data that has passed validation goes
DataRecords[ii].destination,
DataRecords[ii].type,
DataRecords[ii].port,
DataRecords[ii].data);
  }
fclose(DFile);
fclose(ErrorFile);
fclose(DataFile);
printf("\nNumber of errors: %i \n", Ecount);       
printf("Number of saved records: %i ", Count);
free(DataRecords);

}
return 0;
}
```

This is some of the data it needs to validate.

```
0005:0002:0002:0020:100000000000000000017
0001:0002:0002:0080:</BODY>
0006:0003:0002:0041:100000000000000000019
0006:0002:0002:0060:100000000000000000020
0002:0004:0002:0090:100000000000000000022
0001:0002:0003:0021:cp /etc/hosts /root
0002:0004:0002:0010:100000000000000000023
0003:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000025
```

Comment: I don't see the declaration of `DataFile`

Comment: sorry, it is there but i forgot to post that part of the code in

Comment: As it is, this doesn't compile. You might want to delete it, fix it, and undelete when *really* ready.

Comment: ok that has been changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Readability

This code is very hard to read and review, for many reasons:

- Messy indenting: some code blocks are correctly indented (the `struct`), but most of the rest is not, the `main` function has a mix of various inexplicable indents
- Very long lines: avoid long lines. Try to stay within ~80 characters when possible
- As a general rule, comments should be on their own line. This will immediately make the code more readable, as I won't have to scroll to the far right to read something and then scroll back to the left to see the code

#### Naming

Use lowercase names for variables. For example, `dataFile` instead of `DataFile`.

Since you use `TempS`, `TempD`, ... are intended to be used at some point as fields of the `packet struct`, it would be better to name them after those fields in the first place:

- `tempSource` instead of `TempS` for the `source` field
- `tempDestination` instead of `TempD` for the `destination` field
- ... and so on

The traditional loop variable is `i`, it would be just more natural to use that instead of `ii`.

#### Magic numbers

Some numbers appear multiple times. Their purpose is unclear, and if you ever change it in one place, you'll have to remember to change everywhere.
To prevent possible errors, it's better to define constants for them.
For example for the number 71.

#### Security

In general, `strcpy` is not safe, because it may overwrite beyond the end of the destination array. This line is immediately suspicious:

> ```
> strcpy(ErrorLine, DataLine);
> ```

On closer look, I see that both `ErrorLine` and `DataLine` have the same size,
so it should be ok, but it would be better if this was obvious without thinking, by using `strncpy`, and using a named constant as the size parameter, the same constant used in the declaration of the destination array (as I pointed out in the previous point).

Comment: Use of `strncpy(x,y,n)` has it own set of issues.  e.g.  `strncpy(x,y,sizeof x)` does not guarantee `x` is `'\0'` terminated.  Properly using `strncpy()` is on the same order of difficulty of using `strcpy()` but with less performance.  Suggest posting your recommended safe usage of `strncpy()` for the code.

Answer (score 3):

- You need a lot more error checking in your code.
- You don’t need to use `malloc`, since you can process one record at a time.
- Using `atoi` may be ok for very simple cases, but when you write a *validator*, you should be as strict as possible. In that case `strtol` is more complicated to use but still better.
- The `strtok` function can return `NULL`. You need to check for that special return value. Otherwise your program will crash.

Here is the code that can handle overly long lines and malformed integers in the first fields:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int next_int(char *line, int min, int max)
{
    const char *token;
    char *end;
    long number;

    token = strtok(line, ":");
    errno = 0;
    if (token == NULL)
        return -1;
    number = strtol(token, &end, 10);
    if (*end == '\0' && errno == 0 && min <= number && number <= max)
        return number;
    return -1;
}

static int validate_file(const char *in, const char *out, const char *err)
{
    int rv = -1;
    FILE *fin = NULL, *fout = NULL, *ferr = NULL;
    char line[71], linecopy[71];
    int source, destination, type, port;
    const char *data;
    int count = 0, errors = 0;

    if ((fin = fopen(in, "r")) == NULL)
        goto cleanup;
    if ((fout = fopen(out, "w")) == NULL)
        goto cleanup;
    if ((ferr = fopen(err, "w")) == NULL)
        goto cleanup;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fin) != NULL) {
        strcpy(linecopy, line);
        source = next_int(line, 1, 1024);
        destination = next_int(NULL, 1, 1024);
        type = next_int(NULL, 0, 10);
        port = next_int(NULL, 1, 1024);
        data = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        if (source != -1 && destination != -1 && type != -1 && port != -1
            && data != NULL && 1 <= strlen(data) && strlen(data) <= 50) {
            count++;
            fprintf(fout, "%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s\n", source, destination,
                    type, port, data);
        } else {
            errors++;
            fprintf(ferr, "Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s\n", errors, source,
                    destination, type, port,
                    data != NULL ? data : "(null)");
            fprintf(ferr, "%s\n", strtok(linecopy, "\n"));

        }
    }
    rv = 0;

  cleanup:
    if (ferr != NULL) {
        if (fclose(ferr) == -1)
            rv = -1;
    }
    if (fout != NULL) {
        if (fclose(fout) == -1)
            rv = -1;
    }
    if (fin != NULL) {
        if (fclose(fin) == -1)
            rv = -1;
    }
    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    validate_file("data.txt", "data2.txt", "errors.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Some test data:

```
1:1:1:1:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa overly long line
1a:1:1:1:invalid source
1:1a:1:1:invalid destination
1:1:1a:1:invalid type
1:1:1:1a:invalid port
10000:1:1:1:too large source
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I should learn alot from this, but I must ask, if I was to change my code so the program still works as it does now but the code would be using the strtok and strtol function, what would I change specifically? as I would like to keep the core features of my program the same, but it seems quite complicated changing it to fit what you have shown me if that makes sense.

Comment: Mixing the return status and return value from `next_int` is not really to be recommended. Better to keep status separate.  Also is encapsulating `strtok` (with its static storage of the next string pointer) within `next_int` such a good design?

Comment: Concerning `next_int("", -100, 100)`, would not `""` get passed to `strtol()` and return `0`?  Maybe the corner case is not important.  What about `next_int("-1", -100, 100)` returning `-1`?  How does that differ from failure?

Comment: @WilliamMorris: No, mixing this is not a good idea, but it gets the job done in this case. This is just a program to get a simple job done, not a library for others to use, so this is fine. But only in this case. – @chux: `next_int` is not supposed to handle negative numbers, so you are right: I should have used `unsigned int` instead of `int`. For an empty string `strtol` may return anything, but `errno` will be nonzero, and the code checks for that.

Comment: @user3521585: When you change `atoi` to `strtol`, you first have to read and understand the documentation of the `strtol` function, which is quite complex. You have to check all the things that my code checks, which makes your code very long with repetitions. This is the reason why I moved all this code into its own function. You can leave out this separate function and write everything in your `main` function. To do this, you have to declare the variables from the `next_int` function in `main` and replace the `return` from `next_int` with `Flag = 1`, like your code already looks now.

Comment: Getting the job done is not the same as giving good advice. You are suggesting a programming style that is generally discouraged. It is not even simpler or easier to say `x = fn(); if (x < 0) {...}` than to separate return and status with `if (fn(&x) < 0) {...}`

Answer (score 3):

A few comments:

- Most programs are not written entirely in `main`.  It is normal to write
  functions to do individual part of the program.
- Many C programs use the command line and `stdout`/`stderr`.  In the case of
  your program, the filename(s) would be read from the command line and the
  output written to `stdout`.  Errors
  would be written to `stderr` (eg using `fprintf(stderr, "...");`).  This fits with the general UNIX philosphy.
- variables should frequently be declared and initialised at or near the point
  of first use.  So your list of variables at the top would occur later
  (although when sperated into functions they would be in functions).
  Also instead of this sort of thing:

  ```
  struct packet *DataRecords;
  DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
  ...
  FILE *DataFile;
  if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {...}
  ```

  do:

  ```
  struct packet *DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
  if (DataRecords == NULL) {...}
  ...
  FILE *DataFile = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (DataFile == NULL) {...}
  ```

  note the check for `malloc` failure - you should check each `malloc` and
  `realloc`.
- buffer limits are better written using `sizeof` where possible, for example:

  ```
  while (fgets(data, sizeof(data), file) != NULL) {...}
  ```

  This avoids problems if the buffer is later resized.  Beware that if `data` here were a pointer then you would need `sizeof(*data)`. And that only works if the size of `*data` is knowable at compile time. Note that you don't handle lines that are longer than you expect - a usable program would do so.
- you can avoid allocating/reallocating by writing the output as you go, not
  accumulating it in your structure.
- your comments are mostly 'noise'.  They add nothing that people cannot see
  for themselves.  Comments should generally explain why something is done,
  not what is being done.  In a program like this there is no 'why' to explain
  so there should be few, if any comments.  If there is a 'why' (or 'how')
  that needs explaining, think first whether your code could be written in
  such a way that the reason is obvious.
- your list of `strtok`, `strcpy`, `atoi` calls may work at a simple level but
  it lacks good error handling.  To do a thorough job of parsing string input
  is very difficult.  It is good to learn about the C standard library string
  handling functions, but C isn't really suited to such jobs.  A few gotchas:

  - `strcpy` is unsafe as it can overflow silenty - for example if any of
    your numbers (between the colons) is > 4 chars then TempStorage will
    overflow and your program is dead or at least compromised.
  - `strncpy` is also unsafe, although it is somewhat better than `strcpy`.
    On overflow it leaves the target string unterminated.
  - `strtok` will return NULL if the token is not found.  In addition it
    stores a temporary pointer locally and so is not reentrant (i.e. it is not
    safe to use when there are multiple threads) `strtok_r` is preferred.
- your variable names are weak.  `TempS` and its variants are bad names -
  names that vary by just one character are usually best avoided.  These names
  give no indication of what is stored. `Flag` is also weak - it indicates an
  error doesn't it? So why not call it `error`?  In fact it isn't needed:

  ```
  if ((strlen(TempData) < 1 || strlen(TempData) > 50)
      || (TempD < 1 || TempD > 1024)
      || (TempP < 1 || TempP > 1024)
      || (TempS < 1 || TempS > 1024)
      || (TempT < 0 || TempT > 10)) {....}
  ```

  those numbers need to be expressed as constants too.
- your file name `scanf` gives a compiler warning (gcc option -Wformat):

  ```
  char filename[32] = { '\0' } ;
  scanf("%s", &filename);

  code.c:29:17: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
        'char (*)[32]' [-Wformat]
      scanf("%s", &filename);
             ~~   ^~~~~~~~~
  ```

  This would normally be:

  ```
  char filename[32] = "";
  scanf("%s", filename);
  ```

  note that there is no & on the use of `filename`.  This still suffers from a lack of any protection against the file name exceeding 32 chars.  This is a good reason for taking the file name from the command line instead of reading it.